# an error occurred while processing this directive - Magento Multistore

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite, litespeed

I have set up a new site with Magento, for my second site I'm using a subdomain, but when everything seems to be working the new site in the subdomains shows this message [an error occurred while processing this directive] in the shopping cart, my account, whishlist, etc.
You can check it here: [medicamentos.luaterra.com](http://medicamentos.luaterra.com)

What I did was to add this code into the root htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*medicamentos\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:medicamentos] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*medicamentos\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_TYPE:website]
```

And the subdomain is parked, pointing to the root of my magento. The folder has the right permissions and no error logs.
My shared hosting uses Litespedd, so I used RewriteCond.

Wondering if someone very kind can help me :)

Comment: The host actually is `medicamentos.luaterra.com`, and you're trying to match: `medicamentos\.com`

Comment: Hi, thanks I know... sorry I posted something I was trying. Actually I have it as medicamentos.luaterra\.com and still not working. Also I have choosen another template and still showing the one used for the main website. What I understand from the code is: if I go to medicamentos.luaterra.com the website: medicamentos will be displayed, right? I know there is something missing but cannot find it.